# Qemu error uncaught target signal 6 (Aborted) - core dumped on apple mac M1 chip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, bundler, apple-m1

I am trying to  run `make docker` for a cloned repo on my M1 chip mac but it keeps aborting sending Qemu error

> error uncaught target signal 6 (Aborted) - core dumped

the bug error message appears after running bundler within the `make docker` downloading command

```
     % make docker
Login Succeeded
[+] Building 24.9s (10/17)                                                                                                                       
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                        0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring context: 35B                                                                                                            0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/mailtop/passenger:2.7.1-1                                                                        1.9s
 => [ 1/13] FROM docker.io/mailtop/passenger:2.7.1-1@sha256:70c7ec5768a7c9f2238b4282002ed34087f70639e682f63dcde4d879c206553b                0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                           0.1s
 => => transferring context: 108.07kB                                                                                                       0.1s
 => CACHED [ 2/13] WORKDIR /tmp                                                                                                             0.0s
 => CACHED [ 3/13] RUN mkdir ~/.magick &&   cd ~/.magick &&   curl https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/scripts/imagick_type_gen > type_ge  0.0s
 => CACHED [ 4/13] COPY Gemfile Gemfile                                                                                                     0.0s
 => CACHED [ 5/13] COPY Gemfile.lock Gemfile.lock                                                                                           0.0s
 => ERROR [ 6/13] RUN gem install bundler &&   bundle install --jobs $(nproc) --retry 3                                                    22.7s
------                                                                                                                                           
 > [ 6/13] RUN gem install bundler &&   bundle install --jobs $(nproc) --retry 3:                                                                
#0 9.969 Successfully installed bundler-2.4.6
#0 9.969 1 gem installed
#0 22.60 Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.SEGV received in SEGV handler
#0 22.64 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/bundler-2.4.6/lib/bundler/worker.rb:90: [BUG] qemu: uncaught target signal 6 (Aborted) - core dumped
#0 22.69 Aborted
------
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c gem install bundler &&   bundle install --jobs $(nproc) --retry 3]: exit code: 134
make: *** [docker] Error 17
```

[image: 1]

I ran `make clean` and the tried `make docker` again but still have the same  bug

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: It looks like the `gem` command crashed out hard. You should focus on trying to reproduce that issue first. I think the `docker` part is unrelated.

Comment: @tadman The same repo works on my ubuntu with no problem as far as I have seen it's a platform issue with Quemo because of the arm64 and amd64 between M1 chip and intel but I have no clue how to fix that

Comment: This is likely a software defect, but the question is *which* software.